# Load a javascript and css file on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to load a JavaScript and CSS file when I click a button. I've tried a lot of methods and a few are working but they only allow immediate execution with predefined functions and I at least don't want to have to predefine the functions. All I want to do is load a new JavaScript and CSS file from my server and execute (at least the JavaScript) it whenever I want.

Comment: Since you put the jQuery tag, I'll refer you to the AJAX documentation. [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Take a look at dataType: script.

Comment: Why? You can use the `onmouseup` event to run JavaScript functions that can even toggle a class that you the use as a CSS selector. No need to load them later.

Comment: You have to provide concrete example of what you are looking for, your question is quite unclear without any sample. Maybe you want http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ or http://api.jquery.com/load/ or...?

Comment: So you want to split the loading of the file from the execution? This makes only sense if you expect a long load time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add javascript dynamically but the only the way that worked to me always is:

```
var path_to_script = "the url";
var response = syncRequest("GET", path_to_script, null);

var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.text = response;
head.appendChild(script);


function syncRequest(_method, _url, _data) {
    var req = getXmlHttp();
    try{
        req.open(_method, _url, false);
        req.send(_data);
     }catch(e){
            alert(e.description);
     }
     return req.responseText;
}

function getXmlHttp() {
    var xml_http = null;
    if (window.XDomainRequest) { xml_http = new XDomainRequest(); }
    else { xml_http = new XMLHttpRequest; }
    return xml_http;
}
```

I am not sure that ajax request will work, it is partially copy paste from my project with many changes,  but I think it easy to understand how it should to work.

CSS loading:

```
var css = document.createElement("link");
css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
css.setAttribute("href", path_to_css);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
```

Comment: This works fine, one more question though: after I load the javascript file I also load new content using ajax but the jquery binders (in the just loaded javascript file) for the new loaded content don't work at all, any ideas?

Comment: Already solved this myself! Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <link id="custom_stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
    <script id="custom_script"></script>

    <script>
    function LoadStyleAndScript() 
    {
        $("#custom_stylesheet").attr("href", "//example.com/mystyle.css");
        $("#custom_script").attr("src", "//example.com/myscript.js");
    }
    </script>

    <input type="button" onClick="LoadStyleAndScript();" value="Load it">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have an iframe inside a hidden div and load a javascript file in that based on what the user clicks.  The problem will be passing javascript variables.  You'll need to predefine them in PHP before you render the page in the iframe.

If you just load a javascript file and add to the current document body I don't think it will work in terms of using global variables (unless, again, you predefine them with PHP).